# Is it possible to have variable dot accessors in Python 2.6 / Django1.3?

Tags: python, django

This is a contrived example of what i'm asking for:

```
random_list = []
random_uuid = "1234567890-1234567890"
model_instance = Model.objects.filter(related_link=random_uuid)
for x in ['foo', 'bar', 'ray', 'mee']:
    random_list.append(model_instance.x)
```

The three obligatory questions:

- Is this possible?
- If so how?
- Are there any downsides?

Comment: Maybe this 'bunch' example will help: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52308-the-simple-but-handy-collector-of-a-bunch-of-named/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure, just use [getattr](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
for x in ['foo', 'bar', 'ray', 'mee']:
    random_list.append(getattr(model_instance, x))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for x in ['foo', 'bar', 'ray', 'mee']:
    random_list.append(getattr(model_instance, x))
```

(edit: getattr sorry not get)